# Problems with chart.js using Laravel 7, Cannot find element: #app?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, chart.js

I'm using chart.js for showing statistics of reviews and messages of a user, but I'm getting problems with the scripts, now the stats are working but I got this error **Cannot find element: #app** and I don't know how to manage that.

If I use defer in this script (now I deleted it to see the stats working, but all the rest of the website don't)

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

the stats doesn't work anymore and I get also another error like **Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side effects in your templates, such as , as they will not be parsed.**

So if I use defer i got errors, if I don't use defer it cannot find #app.

What should I do? Please help me, it's very important!

**My app.blade.php file (where the script from before is)**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    {{-- <title>{{ config("app.name", "Bool n Roll") }}</title> --}}
    <title>Bool 'n' Roll</title>

    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

    <link rel="icon" href="{{asset('images/favicon.ico')}}" type="image/x-icon"/>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md  shadow-sm bg-nav fixed-nav">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    <img style="height: 50px;" src="{{ asset('images/logorock.png') }}" alt="">
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler bg-dark" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li class="nav-item login-link rounded ml-2">
                                <a class="nav-link text-white px-2" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            @if (Route::has('register'))
                                <li class="nav-item register-link rounded ml-2">
                                    <a class="nav-link title-orange px-2" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Sei un musicista? Registrati!') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle title-orange" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ ucfirst(Auth::user()->name) }}
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/admin">
                                        Dashboard
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main>
            @yield('content')
        </main>

        <footer class="bg-dark text-white py-5">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <img style="height: 50px;" src="{{ asset('/images/footer-logo.png') }}" alt="">
                        <h5 class="my-3">Made with <span class="title-pink">&hearts;</span> from Team 4</h5>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <h5>Dev Team</h5>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li><a class="footer-list title-yellow" href="https://github.com/RobertoZeppilli">Roberto Zeppilli</a></li>
                            <li><a class="footer-list title-petrol" href="https://github.com/Edomak">Edoardo Maccherini</a></li>
                            <li><a class="footer-list title-orange" href="https://github.com/fabiopiro">Fabio Piroddi</a></li>
                            <li><a class="footer-list title-pink" href="https://github.com/michelafranchini">Michela Franchini</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <h5 class="my-3">Sei un musicista?</h5>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li class="nav-item register-link rounded">
                                <a class="nav-link title-orange" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Registrati subito!') }}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    
                    
                </div>

            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @yield('script')
    

    
</body>
</html>
```

**My stat view**
Here I think I got major problems, maybe the script are not correct? Or there's a better way to place them inside the workflow?

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="my_container">
  <h1 class="stat_title">Le tue statistiche</h1>
  @if (count($messages) == 0 && count($reviews) == 0)
      <h2 id="empty_page">Non hai statistiche disponibili</h2>
  @else

  <div class="chart_1">
    <h4>Numero di messaggi e recensioni ricevute ogni mese</h4>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="chart_1">
    <h4>Voti ricevuti ogni mese</h4>
    <canvas id="myOtherChart"></canvas>
  </div>
  @endif
  <p class="link_dashboard"><a href="{{ route('admin.welcome') }}">Torna alla Dashboard</a></p>
</div>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-Wt1bJGtlnMtGP0dqNFH1xlkLBNpEodaiQ8ZN5JLA5wpc1sUlk/O5uuOMNgvzddzkpvZ9GLyYNa8w2s7rqiTk5Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.10.6/dayjs.min.js" integrity="sha512-bwD3VD/j6ypSSnyjuaURidZksoVx3L1RPvTkleC48SbHCZsemT3VKMD39KknPnH728LLXVMTisESIBOAb5/W0Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


<script>dayjs().format()</script>


<script>

  dayjs().format()
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var ct2 = document.getElementById('myOtherChart');
var commenti = {!! $reviews->toJson() !!};
var messaggi = {!! $messages->toJson() !!};
// console.log(commenti.length);
// console.log(messaggi.length);
var now = dayjs();
if (commenti[0]) {
  var primaDataCommento = commenti[0].created_at;
  var date1 = dayjs(primaDataCommento);
} else {
  var date1 = now;
}
const primaDataMessaggio = messaggi[0].created_at;
const date2 = dayjs(primaDataMessaggio);
var datex;
if (date2 < date1) {
  datex = date2;
} else {
  datex = date1;
}
var diff = now.diff(datex, 'month');
var diffRece = now.diff(date1, 'month');
var months = [];
var monthsRece = [];
var recensioniMese = [];
var messaggiMese = [];
var voto1 = [];
var voto2 = [];
var voto3 = [];
var voto4 = [];
var voto5 = [];
// prima tabella
var x = 1;
let i = 0;
if (datex.$M == 0) {
  diff++;
  i++;
  x--;
}
for (i; i <= diff; i++) {
  var numeroMese = datex.$M + i + x;
  months.push(numeroMese + '/2021');
  var countRec = 0;
  var countMes = 0;
  for (let j = 0; j < commenti.length; j++) {
    if (numeroMese == dayjs(commenti[j].added_on).$M + 1) {
      countRec++;
    }
  }
  for (let j = 0; j < messaggi.length; j++) {
    if (numeroMese == dayjs(messaggi[j].added_on).$M + 1) {
      countMes++;
   }
  }
  recensioniMese.push(countRec);
  messaggiMese.push(countMes);
}
// seconda tabella
x = 1;
i = 0;
if (date1.$M == 0) {
  diffRece++;
  i++;
  x--;
}
for (i; i <= diff; i++) {
  var numeroMeseRece = date1.$M + i + x;
  monthsRece.push(numeroMeseRece + '/2021');
  var countRece1 = 0;
  var countRece2 = 0;
  var countRece3 = 0;
  var countRece4 = 0;
  var countRece5 = 0;
  for (let j = 0; j < commenti.length; j++) {
    if (numeroMeseRece == dayjs(commenti[j].created_at).$M + 1) {
      switch (commenti[j].vote) {
        case 1:
          countRece1++;
          break;
        case 2:
          countRece2++;
          break;
        case 3:
          countRece3++;
          break;
        case 4:
          countRece4++;
          break;
        case 5:
          countRece5++;
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  voto1.push(countRece1);
  voto2.push(countRece2);
  voto3.push(countRece3);
  voto4.push(countRece4);
  voto5.push(countRece5);
}
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: months,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Numero di recensioni',
            data: recensioniMese,
            backgroundColor: [
                '#0000ff8c',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                '#0000ff',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        {
            label: 'Numero di messaggi ricevuti',
            data: messaggiMese,
            backgroundColor: [
                '#ff00c88c',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                '#ff00c8',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        },
      ]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                ticks: {
                stepSize: 1
              }
            }
        }
    }
});
var myChart = new Chart(ct2, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: monthsRece,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Recensioni con voto 1',
            data: voto1,
            backgroundColor: [
                '#ff00008c',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'red',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        {
            label: 'Recensioni con voto 2',
            data: voto2,
            backgroundColor: [
                '#ffa6008c',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'orange',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        {
            label: 'Recensioni con voto 3',
            data: voto3,
            backgroundColor: [
                '#ffff008c',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'yellow',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        {
            label: 'Recensioni con voto 4',
            data: voto4,
            backgroundColor: [
                '#b7dd298c',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                '#b7dd29',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        {
            label: 'Recensioni con voto 5',
            data: voto5,
            backgroundColor: [
                '#57e32c8c',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                '#57e32c',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        },
      ]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                ticks: {
                stepSize: 1
              }
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>


@endsection
```

**The app.js file**
Maybe the problem is here? I was trying to wrap the vue instance inside an addEventListener('load') or something to load the instance later, but it didn't work.

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import router from './router';

var dayjs = require('dayjs')
// dayjs().format()

import Vue from 'vue';
import VueCarousel from 'vue-carousel';
Vue.use(VueCarousel);

// import Vue from "vue";


/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */



const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    dayjs,

});
```

**The StatController**
Everything is ok here, I'll leave it here just to show you the complete workflow of getting the statistics of reviews and messages of a user

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Musician;
use App\Message;
use App\Review;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class StatController extends Controller
{
    
    public function showStats(){


        // prendo i dati del dottore registrato
        

        $musician = Musician::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();
        // accedo alle tabelle dei messaggi e recensioni per prenderne i dati
        $messages = Message::where('musician_id', $musician->id)->get();

        $reviews = Review::where('musician_id', $musician->id)->get();


        return view('admin.musicians.stats', compact('musician', 'messages', 'reviews'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update you `app.blade.php`. Remove this `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>` from header and put in body after footer.

```
...

<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

@yield('script')
    
</body>
</html>
```

Then use `@stack('script')` to load other script after app.js, update your `My Stat View`

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="my_container">
  <h1 class="stat_title">Le tue statistiche</h1>
  @if (count($messages) == 0 && count($reviews) == 0)
      <h2 id="empty_page">Non hai statistiche disponibili</h2>
  @else

  <div class="chart_1">
    <h4>Numero di messaggi e recensioni ricevute ogni mese</h4>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="chart_1">
    <h4>Voti ricevuti ogni mese</h4>
    <canvas id="myOtherChart"></canvas>
  </div>
  @endif
  <p class="link_dashboard"><a href="{{ route('admin.welcome') }}">Torna alla Dashboard</a></p>
</div>
@endsection

@push('script')
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-Wt1bJGtlnMtGP0dqNFH1xlkLBNpEodaiQ8ZN5JLA5wpc1sUlk/O5uuOMNgvzddzkpvZ9GLyYNa8w2s7rqiTk5Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.10.6/dayjs.min.js" integrity="sha512-bwD3VD/j6ypSSnyjuaURidZksoVx3L1RPvTkleC48SbHCZsemT3VKMD39KknPnH728LLXVMTisESIBOAb5/W0Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


<script>dayjs().format()</script>


<script>

  dayjs().format()
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var ct2 = document.getElementById('myOtherChart');
var commenti = {!! $reviews->toJson() !!};
var messaggi = {!! $messages->toJson() !!};
// console.log(commenti.length);
// console.log(messaggi.length);
var now = dayjs();
if (commenti[0]) {
  var primaDataCommento = commenti[0].created_at;
  var date1 = dayjs(primaDataCommento);
} else {
  var date1 = now;
}
const primaDataMessaggio = messaggi[0].created_at;
const date2 = dayjs(primaDataMessaggio);
var datex;
if (date2 < date1) {
  datex = date2;
} else {
  datex = date1;
}
var diff = now.diff(datex, 'month');
var diffRece = now.diff(date1, 'month');
var months = [];
var monthsRece = [];
var recensioniMese = [];
var messaggiMese = [];
var voto1 = [];
var voto2 = [];
var voto3 = [];
var voto4 = [];
var voto5 = [];
// prima tabella
var x = 1;
let i = 0;
if (datex.$M == 0) {
  diff++;
  i++;
  x--;
}
for (i; i <= diff; i++) {
  var numeroMese = datex.$M + i + x;
  months.push(numeroMese + '/2021');
  var countRec = 0;
  var countMes = 0;
  for (let j = 0; j < commenti.length; j++) {
    if (numeroMese == dayjs(commenti[j].added_on).$M + 1) {
      countRec++;
    }
  }
  for (let j = 0; j < messaggi.length; j++) {
    if (numeroMese == dayjs(messaggi[j].added_on).$M + 1) {
      countMes++;
   }
  }
  recensioniMese.push(countRec);
  messaggiMese.push(countMes);
}
// seconda tabella
x = 1;
i = 0;
if (date1.$M == 0) {
  diffRece++;
  i++;
  x--;
}
for (i; i <= diff; i++) {
  var numeroMeseRece = date1.$M + i + x;
  monthsRece.push(numeroMeseRece + '/2021');
  var countRece1 = 0;
  var countRece2 = 0;
  var countRece3 = 0;
  var countRece4 = 0;
  var countRece5 = 0;
  for (let j = 0; j < commenti.length; j++) {
    if (numeroMeseRece == dayjs(commenti[j].created_at).$M + 1) {
      switch (commenti[j].vote) {
        case 1:
          countRece1++;
          break;
        case 2:
          countRece2++;
          break;
        case 3:
          countRece3++;
          break;
        case 4:
          countRece4++;
          break;
        case 5:
          countRece5++;
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  voto1.push(countRece1);
  voto2.push(countRece2);
  voto3.push(countRece3);
  voto4.push(countRece4);
  voto5.push(countRece5);
}
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: months,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Numero di recensioni',
            data: recensioniMese,
            backgroundColor: [
                '#0000ff8c',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                '#0000ff',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        {
            label: 'Numero di messaggi ricevuti',
            data: messaggiMese,
            backgroundColor: [
                '#ff00c88c',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                '#ff00c8',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        },
      ]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                ticks: {
                stepSize: 1
              }
            }
        }
    }
});
var myChart = new Chart(ct2, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: monthsRece,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Recensioni con voto 1',
            data: voto1,
            backgroundColor: [
                '#ff00008c',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'red',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        {
            label: 'Recensioni con voto 2',
            data: voto2,
            backgroundColor: [
                '#ffa6008c',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'orange',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        {
            label: 'Recensioni con voto 3',
            data: voto3,
            backgroundColor: [
                '#ffff008c',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'yellow',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        {
            label: 'Recensioni con voto 4',
            data: voto4,
            backgroundColor: [
                '#b7dd298c',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                '#b7dd29',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        {
            label: 'Recensioni con voto 5',
            data: voto5,
            backgroundColor: [
                '#57e32c8c',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                '#57e32c',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        },
      ]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                ticks: {
                stepSize: 1
              }
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>
@endpush
```

Comment: Great man, thanks a lot! I did use b:push with the script in stats.blade, but never think about using b:stack to contain that script. Awesome!!!

Comment: @Robbbb no problem